# How to define a foreign key in the same line where the column is being defined?

Tags: sql, oracle, syntax, foreign-keys, oracle12c

I am learning to use Oracle 12.1.

What's wrong with the foreign key definition below?

```
set echo on
drop table city;
drop table emp;

create table city (
    id number primary key,
    name varchar2(20)
);

create table emp (
    id number,
    cityid number foreign key references city(id)
);
```

When I execute it, I get the following error.

```
$ sqlplus / as sysdba @foo.sql
...
...
SQL>
SQL> create table city (
  2      id number primary key,
  3      name varchar2(20)
  4  );

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> create table emp (
  2      id number,
  3      cityid number foreign key references city(id)
  4  );
    cityid number foreign key references city(id)
                  *
ERROR at line 3:
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
```

I thought it was valid to define foreign key constraint for a column in the same line where the column is being defined.

I am using the syntax defined under http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp > SQL FOREIGN KEY Constraint on CREATE TABLE > SQL Server / Oracle / MS Access.

Is this syntax really invalid in Oracle 12.1?

Comment: use just `cityid number   references city(id)` or `cityid CONSTRAINT some_name REFERENCES city(id)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_7002.htm) the syntax to create a constraint while defining a column does not allow the usage of `foreign key` keywords; your statement should be:

```
create table emp (
    id number,
    cityid number references city(id)
);
```

If you want to name your constraint, without creating it with a separate statement, you can use:

```
create table emp (
    id number,
    cityid number constraint CONSTRAINT_NAME references city(id)
);
```

Comment: This is slightly misleading. In an in-line constraint (that is, defined at the column level), the keywords FOREIGN KEY are prohibited (which is different from "do not need"). Also, FOREIGN KEY is not a clause, it's just two keywords. (The clause is an in-line constraint clause, only the syntax is different.) On the other hand, in an out-of-line constraint (defined at the table level, not at the column level) the keywords FOREIGN KEY are **required**. https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/clauses002.htm#CJAGIICD

Answer (score 0):

You can try this approach

```
create table emp (
id number,
cityid number, CONSTRAINT cityid_fk FOREIGN KEY (cityid)  REFERENCES city(id)
);
```

That is the same was above :)

The only difference is that you are defining the constraint name "cityid_fk", and in the other example oracle will give you a default name like (CONSTRAINT "CONSTRAINT_NAME")